# mbed combining two programs

Tags: c++, mbed

I am trying to get my board connected to ethernet to do so I am using the code [Nucleo_F746ZG_Ethernet](https://os.mbed.com/users/DieterGraef/code/Nucleo_F746ZG_Ethernet/) this code uses an outdated version of mbed, but as soon as I update it it stops working.

In my own made code I use the newest version of mbed that I need for a few functions.

My question is, can I combine these two into a new code that performs both tasks on different versions of mbed and how would I do so?

Comment: "stops working" is not a problem description

Comment: @VTT Fair enough it doesnt preform the code once uploaded.

Comment: @SamHendriks That's still not very descriptive... Suppose you should attach a debugger and find out a little more. Not unlikely that you triggered some undefined behaviour and ended up in the hard fault interrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a different library to assist me in this matter.
https://os.mbed.com/teams/ST/code/mbed-os-tcp-server-example/
This one does work for what i use but i cant set the ip address for my board.
besides this you can create an web interface with it also.